# Elements Invisible But Still Part of DOM for Manipulation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a number of web pages which use JQUERY to fix the layout based on windows size.  These would include resizing DIV's for a uniform height across columns and different images based on different screen sizes.

Does anyone know if there is a visibility setting or other trick that would keep the affected elements invisible but rendered, so that their size can be checked, manipulated, and THEN made visible for the first time?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Yes,

`visibility` property.

DOM parts hidden by `visibility:hidden` are not visible, but rendered.

Comment: Ira - Note that because the space for the elements is still reserved, you have blank spaces (well, whatever's behind them shows) in your layout until you show them.

Comment: Thank you!  Should help avoid my elements leaping about the page :)